# How would I permanently run python server-side code?

Tags: python, server-side

I am using a tutorial that requires some server side code, but they don't show how to permanently run it. is there any way to do this, maybe with a web server? Here is the code:

```
import socket, threading
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 7976

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen()

clients = []
nicknames = []

def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)

def handle(client):                                         
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(message)
        except:        
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            broadcast('{} left!'.format(nickname).encode('ascii'))
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break

def receive():                                                        
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print("Connected with {}".format(str(address)))       
        client.send('NICKNAME'.encode('ascii'))
        nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)
        print("Nickname is {}".format(nickname))
        broadcast("{} joined!".format(nickname).encode('ascii'))
        client.send('Connected to server!'.encode('ascii'))
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()

receive()
```

Comment: What are you not sure how to do? Are you not sure how to launch a Python script? Are you not sure how to schedule the script to launch when the server boots up, assuming the server might not be running all the time? Do you just want a way to make sure the script will start back up if it closes for whatever reason? You haven't said anything specific at all about what you need or what you have researched already.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to change the code so it makes a web server to run the code

Comment: What do you mean "so it makes a web server to run the code"? What is "it"? You're saying that you want this code to run itself as a web server? What does that mean? If you ran this code on a web server, is it not already doing what you want to do? Are you confused as to what a web server is?

Comment: I'm mainly confused about how I would just make it run permanently without having my laptop on, so if you could help with that it would be nice.

Comment: Okay so you need to run it on a server in the cloud - do you know anything about any cloud services, like AWS or Azure? Have you googled anything like "run a python script in the cloud for free"? If you've thoroughly researched it already and are stuck, we can help you, but this site is not a substitute for basic research.